# Why is 1Password sign-in to new device secure without MFA?

Tags: passwords, password-management, 1password

I'm trying to understand why it's not necessary with MFA in 1Password when signing in to a new device.

This was the case that triggered my curiosity:

1. I created a 1Password account
2. I downloaded the Mac application
3. I installed the Chrome plugin
4. I then went on my IPhone and installed the app there too.

At step no 4 all I needed to provide was my 1Password-password.
Why is this secure? Can't anyone download the 1Password IPhone app and try to guess my password?

I'm guessing my understanding of their security model is seriously flawed, but I'm eager to learn more.

Comment: FWIW, the article at https://blog.1password.com/unlock-sso-deep-dive/ explains in detail the process of enrolling new devices, once one is already, see the "End-to-end encryption when enrolling a new device" section.

Comment: So according to that blog, "all I needed to provide was my 1Password-password" is false. OP also needed to provide a confirmation code generated by the Mac application. That's obviously a form of MFA, so is the real answer here that OP is just wrong?

Comment: To answer my own question, it seems like the enrollment process described in that blog isn't used for Apple devices, and instead they just sync the shared key over iCloud Keychain. I'd argue that's still basically 2FA, but it's definitely a form of 2FA that may have been invisible to OP.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[*Disclosure: I work for AgileBits, the makers of 1Password; and I helped design the system you are describing*]

The security model has some unfamiliar components, but it is presented to users like a normal login, so it is natural that you might think that this suffers from the security weaknesses of traditional logins.

### Secret Key

As 4german correctly pointed out in their answer, your account password is combined on your client with something we call your Secret Key. When you created your account, a 128-bit random Secret Key was generated in your browser on your machine. If you generate your emergency kit, you will see your Secret Key in that. Your Secret Key is absolutely necessary for you to decrypt your data, so do save a copy of your Emergency Kit.

We do have the Secret Key sync to other devices through end-to-end encrypted service that don’t pass through us. Apple’s iCloud Keychain is such a service. And so it made it onto your iPhone where it can be read only by iOS apps signed by AgileBits. It is important that the Secret Key is never handled by our servers, as it is designed to protect you if we were ever to be breached.

#### Not a second factor

In the instance you encountered, the Secret Key is kinda-sorta acting like a second factor, as you must be using a device which has received it independently of 1Password servers, but it is a mistake to think of it generally that way. The Secret Key is designed to protect you if your data is captured from our systems. It makes what we hold truly uncrackable.

You can enable real 2FA for 1Password, which will require a second factor when you set up a new device. 2FA for unlocking encrypted data on an already enrolled device would be security theater.

### Client computation

Your account password and your secret key are your user secrets that are used for two purposes. One purpose is to derive the keys needed to decrypt your data. 1Password can be used off-line this way. The other is to derive a an authentication key (which I will call `x`). The process of deriving these keys from your user secrets is designed to be computationally expensive. So it inherently rate limits guessing, long before a sign in attempt is made to the server.

Unlike traditional authentication, `x` is never sent to the server. Instead the server constructs a mathematical puzzle that can only be solved with knowledge of `x`. The puzzle is different each time you log in.

Additionally, the server proves to the client that it knows a related secret, `v`. `v` was created by your client when you first signed up, and was sent to the server only at first enrollment. As with the client proving to knowledge of `x`, the server’s proof of knowledge of `v` is also a zero-knowledge proof. The server must solve a puzzle that can only be done with knowledge of `v`.

### What this all means

What looks like traditional signin process to users is actually a far more secure system. You can enable 2FA for 1Password if you wish, but it protects you only from the attacker who

1. Can guess your account password
2. Has your Secret Key
3. Does *not* have your encrypted data

The circumstances in which both 2 and 3 might hold are rare.

Comment: I agree with everything here, except that I'd add that "password and secret key but not encrypted data" is less rare if someone were going through your file cabinet and found your emergency kit. That could be a burglar, but it could also just be something like a nosy teenager looking for a credit card. 2FA is a great line of defense in that case.

Comment: @yshavit Then maybe you shouldn't **print out your emergency kit** and 
**put it in an unsecured location**.
Maybe the same users will write their phone password on a post-it and leave the phone on the desk too. 1Password can't protect users from all their stupid.

Comment: @Nelson Firstly, there are nice ways to say everything. :-) Secondly, there are lots of news stories out there of parents who thought they had something important securely stored, only to discover that their kid knew the combo / where the key was / etc. 2FA adds another layer of defense.

Comment: @Nelson Well, consider the average Joe (well, okay, average Joe does not use 1Password. Let's say a friend has convinced them to use it). How are they going to store their emergency kit? Keeping it on their computer is wrong, since it will probably break when they download malware from porn sites, uploading that to Google Drive exposes the secrets to Google. Printing it and storing it in a safe is a reasonable solution, the problem is that most people don't have a proper safe in their house... so they order from amazon a simple security box that their teenager can open with a fork.

Comment: couple of minor typos: "red" instead of "read", "rare" instead of "rate" (limited)

Comment: I feel like @Nelson and Yshavit are both right. We have not found a way to advise people on how to store their EK that will work for most users. Storing it on paper without the password is an option. In my family, we each have a copy of the others' Secret Keys (but I know the all our family members know how to pick good passwords).

Comment: @JeffreyGoldberg That's because there is no one solution that works for most people. Different people have different threat models. For a wealthy loner living in a remote fortified building, a piece of paper in a drawer is probably as secure as you can get. For a homeless person in a shelter, not so much. Unless you're willing to exclude entire categories of customers, you have to recognize different threat models require different solutions. Paper for people with strong physical security but limited technical knowledge is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: @barbecue, that was largely the point. There is no right answer to "where should I put my Secret Key". And so anything we say will be wrong. Instead, we try to explain what it is for. But it is an unusual thing that is hard to understand.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you might not have [MFA enabled on your 1Password account](https://support.1password.com/two-factor-authentication/).

Without MFA, logging into a 1Password account requires your email address, your [Secret Key](https://support.1password.com/secret-key-security/), and your Account Password.

When you login to 1Password for Mac or iOS, 1Password will store your email address and Secret Key in your encrypted iCloud Keychain.

This is how you were able to login on your iPhone with only your account password, because everything else was saved to iCloud Keychain.

Someone else wouldn’t have access to your iCloud Keychain credentials, and therefore would need your email, Secret Key, and account password to access your account on their device.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that Apple had already synced the key secret key, but I wasn't sure if the mechanisms actually were that smart :)